# How can I add an 'and' within if/else in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a few if/else statements which i want to do more than just change the price like they do now. The price's are variables so they change upon different actions on the page.

Now i want the if else statement to work like this:

If (hasclass unselected **AND** x = 500, do something.
Else, do something else

If 2 options hasclass selected, do something else entirely.

```
$('div.unselected-option').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('unselected-option selected-option');

     if ($('div.dc-option1').hasClass("unselected-option")){
         price = price1;
     }

     else {
         price = price1 + price2;
     }

     if ($('div.dc-option2').hasClass("unselected-option")){
         price = price;
     }

     if ($('div.dc-option2').hasClass("selected-option")){
         price = price + price3;
     }

     if ($('div.dc-option3').hasClass("unselected-option")){
         price = price;
     }

     if ($('div.dc-option3').hasClass("selected-option")){
         price = price + price4;
     }

    document.getElementsByClassName("dc-price")[0].innerHTML = '€' + price + ',-';

});
```

Comment: what are you preventing to add that? maybe [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) helps a bit.

Comment: Are you looking for the logical "and" operator? If so, have you tried googling "JavaScript and"?

Comment: Also please: `$(".dc-price").first().html('€' + price + ',-');` -  not to mention removing all the ones with `price = price`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

```
if ($('div.dc-option1').hasClass("unselected-option") && (x==500))
```

Comment: or better `x === 500` with strict and without brackets.

Comment: @Radu  no problem